# SCSS file watcher cannot open file - WebStorm

Tags: sass, webstorm

I can't get WebStorm's SCSS file watcher to compile the Bootstrap SCSS files.

I have downloaded sass-dart for Windows and have tried pointing WebStorm's file watcher to dart-sass\sass.bat and dart-sass\src\dart.exe

The file watcher is enabled, it's not the common issue I've seen in other questions here where the file watcher keeps disabling itself.

Here is the file watcher setup I am using in WebStorm:
[image]

When I use dart-sass\src\dart.exe the result is:

```
Could not load "bootstrap-grid.scss:bootstrap-grid.css": Unknown scheme (bootstrap-grid.scss) for bootstrap-grid.scss:bootstrap-grid.css
null
```

and when I use dart-sass\sass.bat the result is:

`Error reading bootstrap-grid.scss:bootstrap-grid.css: Cannot open file.`

Obviously I'd prefer it to run with no errors and spit out correctly compiled CSS files!

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me using similar watcher setup. What **Working directory:** did you specify for your file watcher? Please make sure that it's set to `$FileDir$`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've checked and $FileDir$ is the working directory

Comment: does the same command work in terminal? cd to your SCSS file dir, the run `path\to\dart-sass\sass.bat <scc_file_name>.scss:<scc_file_name>.css` - what is the result?